# How to Integrate Custom Test Framework with IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, rider

I have been wanting to write my own test framework for a while.  Right now, I have a heavily modified version of MSTest that I use, but I want to write my own test runner so I have complete control over the testing process from start to finish.

After a long session of Googling, I stumbled across this [blog post](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Building-Your-Own-Unit-Testing-Framework-in-C-Part-1.aspx) from 2011 outlining all of the components of a test framework.  The one caveat that I noticed is exclusively a command line application.

I started to dig around in my IDE (I use Rider by Jetbrains) and noticed it has a select number of test runners built in: xUnit, NUnit and MSTest.

Can a new test framework be added to either Rider or Visual Studio?  I assume if it is possible, it would have to be done via a plugin.

If anyone knows of an example that is newer and/or more complete than the one I linked to, that would be awesome as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `NUnit`, for the test cases to run integrated in Visual Studio IDE, you need to install the `NUnit Adapter` extension.

So in your case as well, if you have your own custom unit test framework you will have to write an adapter extension to let visual studio know about you framework. For reference you can look into the NUnit Adapter source code in [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/tree/master/src/NUnitTestAdapter)

Visual Studio, starting from VS 2015, allows to create extensions using the [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) framework (Compiler Platform extension) in simpler way.